# making groups based on match between column 1 and column 2 from 1 table

Tags: sql

Imagine I have the table:

```
+---------+-----+--------+
|  Name   |  ID |  AttID |
+---------+-----+--------+
| PC      |   1 |  NULL  |
| Printer |   2 |  1     |
| Scanner |   3 |  1     |
+---------+-----+--------+
```

How can I write a query to group it on the `ID` level, and subsort on the `AttID`?
I've tried using a self-join with no succes.

Comment: Please post expected output for your data, add a tag of DBMS you are using and show your attempts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `coalesce` can help

```
select *
from your_data
order by coalesce(AttID, ID), id
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c5f8b8816a2101390d480c7fb9aaa369)